# Multiple searches in LIKE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hey guys I'm currently trying to search a table for any location names that start with B or G, I am running into an error when trying to run this code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Location 
WHERE LocName LIKE  'B%' or 'G%'
```

I am a massive SQL noob, infact this is my first ever SQL experience, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try below **Query**. If you want to search records with two conditions, you have write something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Location 
WHERE LocName LIKE 'B%' 
or LocName LIKE 'G%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Location 
WHERE  LocName LIKE 'B%' OR LocName LIKE 'G%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Location 
WHERE LocName LIKE 'B%' or LocName LIKE 'G%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Location WHERE LocName LIKE 'B%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM Location WHERE LocName LIKE 'G%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one with `REGEXP_LIKE` operator

```
SELECT *
FROM location
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (LocName, '^(B|G)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add as much condition as you want by appending Or and writing your condition at the end. Try the following.

```
SELECT * FROM Location 
WHERE LocName LIKE 'B%' 
or LocName LIKE 'G%'
```

The [Live SQL SERVER working fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/356ac/2)

The [Live ORACLE working fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a0e2d/2)